# How do I create a SSH server that runs a program rather than a full shell?

Tags: ssh, shell, remote-access, telnet

I've got a program that I want to share over ssh (or even telnet, security of the program isn't important), but I don't want to allow the connection to access anything else in my system except for the I/O of that one program (e.g. no scp, no full shell access, no ssh tunnels). Is this possible, and how would I go about it on a Ubuntu system?

Bonus points for being able to run this as a local user, or as `nobody`.

Comment: [GNU Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) seems to work to some degree (with `-e`) but can only support one user/session/instance, ideally I'd want to be able to connect more than once without having to restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **GNU Netcat seems to work to some degree (with -e) but can only support one user/session/instance, ideally I'd want to be able to connect more than once without having to restart the server.**

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) can fork.

I suggest browsing it's [examples](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES)

> `socat TCP4-LISTEN:5555,fork,tcpwrap=script \`
>   `EXEC:/bin/myscript,chroot=/home/sandbox,su-d=sandbox,pty,stderr`
>
> a simple server that accepts connections (TCP4-LISTEN) and fork's a new child process for each connection; every child acts as single relay. The client must match the rules for daemon process name "script" in /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny, otherwise it is refused access (see "man 5 hosts_access"). For EXEC'uting the program, the child process chroot's to /home/sandbox, su's to user sandbox, and then starts the program /home/sandbox/bin/myscript. Socat and myscript communicate via a pseudo tty (pty); myscript's stderr is redirected to stdout, so its error messages are transferred via socat to the connected client.

Answer (score 4):

I see two simple approaches:

1. Create local users that get your program executable as login shell.
2. Add an xinetd service that calls your program (user can then telnet to this service)

Answer (score 0):

Create the users that will use the server as follows:

`adduser -s /bin/software username`

Where **/bin/software** is the location of the software and **username** is, well, the username of the user.

Be aware that people can still get access to a shell if they find a security breach in your software.